# How to git log with first-parent and show files affected

Tags: git

I want a log that just shows the commits to the active development branch called `develop` and I want to see the files changed in those commits so I am using the command `git log --first-parent --stat`. Many of the commits are merges to `develop` but the merge commits show no files changed.

Each of those merges into `develop` caused a bunch of files to change all at once in the `develop` branch. I know that originally those changes were broken up into multiple commits in a feature branch but I'm not interested in that, I just want to know about what files changed in `develop` for each commit regardless of whether it is a merge or not. What command will do this?

Answer (score 0):

For files changed between commits try:
git diff [from commit]..[to commit] --name-only

For files changed in commits in your branch's log try:
git log --name-only

If you want to see which files changed in which commits, including merges and where those merges came from you could try:

```
git log --name-only --graph --decorate --all
```

If you're not interested in other unrelated branches, you can remove the --all.